# Compiling plugin in 1.9 Qgis-dev

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am actually learning QGIS and how to develop a plugin. I have to write this plugin in C++ and not python because people coding in C++ want to modify it after.

I have found some plugins in the git repository in C++ and I manage to compile it with 1.9 librairies on QGIS. But it's seems they change the constructor of the QgisPlugin.

QgisPlugin( name_, description_, version_, type_) all the parameters are QString in 1.9 QGIS but "type_" was a QgisPlugin parameter before. I put a string on the constructor and I could compile the plugin in ".dll" but QGIS 1.9 does'nt recognize my plugin.

Do you know where I can found the source of a plugin made in 1.9 ?

Comment: Are you planning on making this plugin public at some stage?

Comment: Yes this is why I have to make it in C++

Comment: Ah sorry I am not english and I confuse two words. No this plugin will not be public, it is similar to "delimited text" but in more light. It will be use for researchs in my company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of plugins live inside the source code. In [src/plugins](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/tree/master/src/plugins) you will find them.

The [QgisPlugin constructor takes 5 arguments](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgisPlugin.html):

```
QgisPlugin( QString const & name = "",
            QString const & description = "",
            QString const & category = "",
            QString const & version = "",
            PLUGINTYPE const & type = MAPLAYER )
```

where the last one is one of the following:

```
enum PLUGINTYPE
{
  UI = 1,                     /* user interface plug-in */
  MAPLAYER,                    /* map layer plug-in */
  RENDERER,                     /*a plugin for a new renderer class*/
};
```